How to create Postgress query with criteria filter
I have to create a query in postgress where I have 2 tables , 1) Request(caseID, quantity, amount)
2) Activity ( caseId , bookingtime ) so I want to create a query which should give me the data from both the table...caseId should be matched...and results columns are date, bookedquantity , amount ..i will pass startdate and enddate from request and it should match that with bookingtime and give me result..since same caseID can be multiple in both table so need data based on date only and so for particular date if two distinct caseId is available..their quantity and amount should get added with other row quantity and amount for particular date but distinct caseid.....i tried many queries but couldn't get expected result. Plz anyone can suggest how can I achieve this.TIA.

Please present a clear question. This is inconsistent and barely readable.

It is hard to tell what is this all about. You realy should provide some sample data, one or more of your attempts, describe logic and issue and provide the expected result that you want from sample data provided.
Below is a blind guess as an answer but you could see the sample data, the code and the result from that sample data. Please provide what's missing since this guess is most probably false:
With     --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    request (caseID, quantity, amount) AS
        ( Select 101, 10, 75 Union All 
          Select 101, 12, 90 Union All 
          Select 101,  6, 45 Union All 
          Select 102,  1, 12 Union All 
          Select 102,  6, 72 Union All 
          Select 103,  1, 15 Union All 
          Select 104,  4, 60 
        ),
    activity (caseID, bookingtime) AS
        ( Select 101,  TIMESTAMP '2024-05-05 10:23:00' Union All
          Select 101,  TIMESTAMP '2024-05-07 11:05:00' Union All
          Select 102,  TIMESTAMP '2024-05-05 14:35:00' Union All
          Select 102,  TIMESTAMP '2024-05-08 16:08:00' Union All
          Select 103,  TIMESTAMP '2024-05-04 08:44:00' Union All
          Select 103,  TIMESTAMP '2024-05-06 09:35:00' Union All
          Select 104,  TIMESTAMP '2024-05-07 15:21:00' 
        )

--    S Q L :
Select      a.bookingtime::date as bookingdate, a.caseID, 
            Sum(r.quantity) as quantity, Sum(r.amount) as amount 
From        activity a
Inner Join  request r ON( r.caseID = a.caseID )
Where       a.bookingtime::date Between '2024-05-05'::date And '2024-05-07'::date
Group By    bookingdate, a.caseID
Order By    bookingdate, a.caseID

/*    R e s u l t :
bookingdate  caseid  quantity  amount
-----------  ------  --------  ------
2024-05-05      101        28     210
2024-05-05      102         7      84
2024-05-06      103         1      15
2024-05-07      101        28     210
2024-05-07      104         4      60    */

